# Upload image from URL using AJAX just like StackOverflow does?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, upload, jquery-file-upload

I am building a Project Management module for SUgarCRM and part of my module consist of a full Discussion Forum.

Now when a user create a new Topic post or a Post reply, I would like to have a button to add an image, it would then allow the user to upload an image and insert the URL of the Uploaded image into the post, it would also allow them to input the URL of an image and it would then upload to our server and insert the URL as if it was uploaded from there computer.

Basically 2 examples that do the exact same thing as I need are GMAIL and StackOverflow.  The images below show the example if it in action on both sites.

I have found a great AJAX upload script http://blueimp.github.io/jQuery-File-Upload/
So I think what I would need to build is the Modal window which would have the uploader and then a tab that allows them to input a URL at which point I need to trigger an upload from URL and then insert into my textarea.

Does anyone have an example of this in action anywhere or know of  library that does this already?

[image]

[image]

Comment: I believe what is happening is StackOverflow is simply sending the URL via and AJAX push to their server, which then sends a request to imgur to upload the photo.

Comment: Easiest way would be passing the url via Ajax/REST post to the server and let it retrieve and store it.  Let it be async Ajax call, and the call return a success/fail to the promise callback.

Comment: @PitaJ That makes sense I think you're right.  When I posted this question I hadn't really put a lot of thought into it but it does appear that is what is happening

Comment: @Jason my comment above to PitaJ applies to you too, seems about right.  To you Jason, when you say "async Ajax call" isn't that how a regular AJAX call using something like jQuery is by default?

Comment: When you do an Ajax call with jQuery, one of the parameterized options is to declare if it's async or not, default is true.

Answer (score -1):

This code use jQuery to load image from url. 
get properties from url :)

html

```
<div id="picture"></div>
```

jQuery

```
var img = new Image();  
img.src = urlimg;
$("#picture").append(img);
img.onload = function(){
      alert(img.width);
}
```

Comment: Actually it download/uploads the image to a different server so that the link you out in, could go down and they still have a copy of the file, it;s done really good. I think the real solution is to pass the URL using JavaScript to the backend scripts which will then upload the file from URL and pass the new URL of the newly uploaded file back to the frontend the image